# Leaking object by calling addChild

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I have a custom class called `Hexagon` which is a subclass from `NSObject`. However when I assign it to a sprite and add it to the screen by calling `-addChild:`, it has a retain count of 2! What should I do, in order to stop that leakage ?

```
 for (int i =0; i < HEXCOUNT; i++){
        Hexagon *nHex = [[Hexagon alloc]initWithDicitonary:hexPositions];
        CCSprite *theSprite = (CCSprite*)nHex;
        NSString *hexName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hexagon%d", i];
        CGPoint location = CGPointFromString([[EXHEXAGONS objectForKey:hexName]objectForKey:@"position"]);
        CGPoint nLocation = ccp(screenSize.width/2 + 68 * location.x,screenSize.height/2 + 39 * location.y);
        theSprite.position = nLocation;

        [self addChild:theSprite z:1 tag:i];

        NSMutableDictionary *hexProperties = [EXHEXAGONS objectForKey:hexName];
        [hexProperties setObject:theSprite forKey:@"realSprite"];
        [EXHEXAGONS setObject:hexProperties forKey:hexName] ;
        [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]setExistingHexagons:EXHEXAGONS];

    [nHex release];

    }
```

Comment: `retainCount` is utterly useless.  Don't call it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't rely on retainCount for anything. A retainCount of 2 doesn't mean the object is leaking. Only Instruments can tell you that.

Creating the Hexagon object with alloc/init will add a retain count of +1. Adding it as child will add +1. So depending on where you log the retainCount, it may be correct.

If you worry about memory leaks, by all means [start using ARC](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/).

Comment: I used instruments in order to detect leaks, and it showed me that exact line of code. And I've just been told the first time (well, I have never researched it) that I can use ARC with cocos2D ... But how do I do that ?

Comment: how to enable ARC for cocos2d: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/
Alternative: use Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com). Has ARC already enabled in all projects.

Comment: I tried to use your (video-)tutorial but it does not work and throws like 70 errors at me. How do I solve that now ? :( By the way, I tried it with a new project as well, it's the same result...

Answer (score 1):

First off, worrying about retain counts is not productive unless you are verifying that it is not getting deallocated when fully released from all the various objects which retain it.

Secondly, presumably you are putting the object into a `NSArray`, `NSSet`, or `NSDictionary` within `addChild:z:tag:`? So, that would bump it's retain count up by one.

You also cast your `Hexagon` object to a `CCSprite` and add it to the `NSDictionary` `hexProperties`, which will add another 1 to your retain count.

By the time you `release` your object at the bottom of the loop, your retain count will be **at least** 3. After the `release` it should be **at least** 2.

Comment: So, how do I prevent it from leaking then ?

Comment: How are you determining you have a leak? At this point you have only expressed concern that the retain count is too high. Have you released the object(s) from `hexProperties` **and** whatever container/object is holding the object(s) from within `addChild`? If at this point you do have a leak (the objects don't get deallocated), then you need to examine what you are doing within `addChild` (and methods it invokes). The problem is not in the above code snippet.